# Angular2: ng2-img-cropper does not crop url image

Tags: image, angular, crop

I am using ng2-img-cropper to crop a photo (not avatar). 
https://github.com/cstefanache/angular2-img-cropper

I followed the example:
https://embed.plnkr.co/V91mKCNkBQZB5QO2MUP4/

I saw that it seems not to support url image, only local image. Is there anyway to make it work with url image?

If not, is there any alternative which can work with url image?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

please check the discussion in the following thread: https://github.com/cstefanache/angular2-img-cropper/issues/110

The idea is to work with something like: 
var image:HTMLImageElement = new Image();
    this.image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    image.src ='https://www.google.ro/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
    image.addEventListener('load', (data) => {
        this.cropper.setImage(image);
    });